# How to manipulate a Laravel collection with related models and return a customized instance?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**My model relation**

```
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Opportunity')->with('user');
```

**My Attempt**

```
$project = Project::find(1);
$$opportunities = $project->opportunities
  ->where('status', "confirmed");


$opportunities->each(function ($opportunity) {
    return $opportunity->get('user');
});
```

**Goal**

My goal is to return the data in the following structure:

```
Opportunities:
  Opportunity:
    Status,
    Amount
    Currency
    Name
```

Note that the user is a subset of the opportunity itself.

**Problem**

This returns a 1024 SQL error.

[image: vel]

**Ideally**

It would be ideal if I can return all this information with *the* query itself.

Comment: This `$oppurtunities = $project->opportunities
  ->where('status', "confirmed")` is not excecuted query. You have to add a `->get()` at the end to execute it, otherwise you will execute it in the `each` with a `get('user')`wich results in the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `get()` method on your query to get its results first:

```php
$oppurtunities = $project->opportunities()
  ->where('status', "confirmed")
  ->get();
```

You have eager loaded the `user` instance for each `opportunity` so just call `$opportunity->user` to return each opportunity's user:

```php
$project = Project::find(1);
$opportunities = $project
    ->opportunities()
    ->where('status', "confirmed")
    ->get();

$filtered = $opportunities->map(function ($opportunity) {
    return [
        'status' => $opportunity->status,
        'amount' => $opportunity->amount_pledged,
        'currency' => $opportunity->currency,
        'name' => optional($opportunity->user)->full_name
   ];
})->all();
```

Comment: I think we are missing a `map()` .

Comment: @AliGajani yes you should use a map, check my updated answer.

Comment: @AliGajani glad it helped, also note that you can chain collections' methods ;)